# Async Task gives warning, (without) Async Task gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

This is probably a more of a finesse question but I have the following method inside a ViewComponent class

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    return View();
}
```

but the name *InvokeAsync* is underlined and gives the following warning

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
>   Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls,
>   or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread

but if I try removing the *async* from the method then *return View()* is underlined with red and outputs the following error

> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.ViewViewComponentResult' to
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'  MVCStateManagement

So my question is what approach should I take? Let the async there indiferently of the warning, or is there a workaround / fix for this warning? Does it have that much of an impact on my project?

Thanks!

Comment: I was following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1#add-a-viewcomponent-class that is why it is defined so.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Good point. See my answer.

Comment: The reason it is async in that tutorial is because in the tutorial it calls an async method: var items = await GetItemsAsync(maxPriority, isDone);.  If you aren't calling an asyc method in your code, then there is no reason to have your method be async.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear why the method was defined as an `async` method that returns a `Task<IViewComponentResult>` in the first place.

Since the method seems to be truly synchronous and simply returns a view, you should probably define it like this:

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
{
    return View();
}
```

A synchronous method doesn't magically become asynchronous just because you add the `async` keyword to it.

If you are implementing an interface and cannot change the signature of the method, you could use the `Task.FromResult` method to return an already completed task (you should still remove the `async` keyword):

```
public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult<IViewComponentResult>(View());
}
```

Comment: @Immorality seems to have answered 1 minute faster than you, but your answer is more detailed. Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 3):

The method runs on a Task of ViewcomponentResult. 
You can call it without async by using this:

```
public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
  return Task.FromResult<IViewComponentResult>(View());
}
```

Your warning will no longer show and your code will run.
You could also leave it. Either will have no impact on the performance of your project.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you would be so kind to mark the answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the async flag and the `Task<>`. Just return a `IViewComponentResult`.

You will tipically return a object wrapped into `Task<>` when you do async work. If you don´t it does not make any sense.

From MSDN:

> The Task class represents a single operation that returns a
>   value and that usually executes asynchronously. Task objects
>   are one of the central components of the task-based asynchronous
>   pattern first introduced in the .NET Framework 4. Because the work
>   performed by a Task object typically executes asynchronously
>   on a thread pool thread rather than synchronously on the main
>   application thread, you can use the Status property, as well as the
>   IsCanceled, IsCompleted, and IsFaulted properties, to determine the
>   state of a task. Most commonly, a lambda expression is used to specify
>   the work that the task is to perform.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

EDIT:

You can also try returning:

```
return Task.FromResult<IViewComponentResult>(View());
```

Comment: If I try to remove the Task<>, only returning an IViewComponentResult the program crashes with this *InvalidOperationException: Method 'InvokeAsync' of view component 'MVCStateManagement.ViewComponents.LayoutHeaderViewComponent' should be declared to return Task<T>.*